# Is there a programatic way to create video content from still images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a set of images I'd like to compile into a video slideshow, with audio (music) and text overlays.

The video could easily be compiled manually, though I want to do it in code so the process can be automated.

I'm on a Mac so [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) won't work. Is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) intended for this type of use case? If not, are there other tools/frameworks that would allow for programmatic creation of video content from still images?

Comment: Since what you're asking is not clear I'm commenting instead of answering. Yes you can use ffmpeg command-line utility to automate this process. Take a look at [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow), and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. You did answer my question though, I'll check out the ffmpeg command line.

Comment: I can copy my comment and paste as an answer if you want to accept it

Comment: Yeah go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ffmpeg intended for this type of use case?

Yes, you can use ffmpeg command-line utility to automate this process. Take a look at [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow), and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1)